# Having trouble with a Javascript callback function building a piano

Tags: javascript, callback, event-listener

I'm about a month in with Javascript and trying to build a piano. My audio is working fine using the keydown event, but now I'm trying to make the specific key of the piano appear as if it was pushed and can't figure this part out.

Other context: despite the audio working, i get the errors in my console log 'whiteKey.contains is not a function' and 'blackKey.contains is not a function'

'white' and 'black' are classes and the default CSS for my white and black keys.

'white-pushed' and 'black-pushed' are also classes with new CSS that, when activated, resemble a key pushed down.

Thanks,

```
const whiteKey = document.getElementsByClassName('white');
const blackKey = document.getElementsByClassName('black');

function whiteKeyDown(){
    if (!whiteKey.contains('white-pushed')){
        whiteKey.add('white-pushed')
    }
}

function blackKeyDown(){
    if (!blackKey.contains('black-pushed')){
        blackKey.add('black-pushed')
    }
}


document.addEventListener('keydown', (playNote) => {
    if(playNote.repeat) return;


    if(playNote.key == 'c'){
        if (playNote.ctrlKey){
            blackKeyDown(document.getElementById('low-c#').play())    
        } else {
            whiteKeyDown(document.getElementById('low-c').play())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you want to check and modify the elements' classes, if that is the case, you need to use something like `whiteKey.classList.contains('white-pushed')` and `whiteKey.classList.add('white-pushed')`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` return an array of elements contain the specifed class name

You can't use `.contains` directly on it, you have to get the specific element from the array returned by the `document.getElementsByClassName()`

For example:

```js
const whiteKey = document.getElementsByClassName('white');

function whiteKeyDown(){
    // whiteKey[0] is the first element that have the 'white' class name on it
    if (!whiteKey[0].classList.contains('white-pushed')) {
        whiteKey[0].classList.add('white-pushed')
    }
}
```

You can read more about the method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)